# Regex for matching parentheses

Tags: regex

I have string :
`select * from workspace populate $intname(Column 5) with column_1 as lookup [(`Office Military`,`OM`)]`

In which I want to match $intname(Column 5)

The regex I have written is :
`\$intname\(.+\)`

which matches `$intname(Column 5) with column_1 as lookup [(`Office Military`,`OM`)`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are there cases with nested parentheses? If yes, what tool/language are you using? If not, you have an answer.

Comment: @stribizhev: there are no nested parentheses. and the answer works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the regex non greedy:

```
\$intname\(.+?\)
```

or

```
\$intname\([^)]+\)
```